# How to find parent tr of td in a table using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am working on asp.net mvc 3. I have a following structure,

```
<tr data-uid="123">
<td>
<a href="#" id="click">Click Me</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Now i want to find the  tag data- attribute value. I have tried like,

```
$("a#click").click(function(){
 var i= $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').data('uid');
});
```

but doesnt work for me. please guide me.

Comment: Your code should work, have you put your code within document ready handler? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: [Your code seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/z78b2/)? What's going wrong for you?

Answer (score 42):

You can use the [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to get the closest parent of the selector that is queried with if don't want to crawl up parent at each level.

```
$("#click").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $i = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-uid');
    console.log($i);

    var $j = $(this).closest('tr').data('uid');
    console.log($j);
});​
```

`e.preventDefault()` is just to prevent the default action.. You can remove that if you do not need it.

Also make sure your `tr` are enclosed inside table tags to make it work..

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/vmTvV/4/)

Answer (score 14):

### Answer

```
$("a#click").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var i = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-uid');
    console.log(i);
    var j = $(this).closest('tr').data('uid');
    console.log(j);
});
```

**[VIEW DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g8MKK/)**

---

### How to find the closest row?

**Using `.closest()`:**

```
var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
```

---

**Using `.parent()`:**

Check this [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method. This is alternative of a `.prev()` and `.next()`.

```
var $row = $(this).parent()             // Moves up from <button> to <td>
                  .parent();            // Moves up from <td> to <tr>
```

---

#### Get All Table Cell **`<td>`**

```
var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),       // Finds the closest row <tr> 
    $tds = $row.find("td");             // Finds all children <td> elements

$.each($tds, function() {               // Visits every single <td> element
    console.log($(this).text());        // Prints out the text within the <td>
});
```

**[VIEW DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CKEc6/1/)**

---

#### Get Only Specific **`<td>`**

```
var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),        // Finds the closest row <tr> 
    $tds = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)"); // Finds the 2nd <td> element

$.each($tds, function() {                // Visits every single <td> element
    console.log($(this).text());         // Prints out the text within the <td>
});
```

**[VIEW DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T9uv7/)**

---

#### Useful methods

- [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) - get the first element that matches the selector
- [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) - get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements
- [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) - get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements
- [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) - get the children of each element in the set of matched elements
- [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) - get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements
- [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) - get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements
- [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) - get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements
- [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) - get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements

Comment: How to traverse through all rows (tr)?

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work as is but you could instead of using multiple .parent() you should use parents('tr'). http://api.jquery.com/parents/

```
$(function() {
  $("a#click").click(function(){
    var i= $(this).parents('tr').data('uid');
  });​
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/mchambaud/G5jM8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `.attr()` ?

```
$("a#click").click(function(){
    var i= $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').attr('data-uid');
    console.log( i );
});
```

Comment: You should not use .attr() for this, as of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object.
http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var i= $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').attr('data-uid');
```

Comment: You should not use .attr() for this, as of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object. api.jquery.com/data

Answer (score 0):

`.closest()` - get the first element that matches the selector
`.parent()` - get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements
`.parents()` - get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements
`.children()` - get the children of each element in the set of matched elements
`.siblings()` - get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements
`.find()` - get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements
`.next()` - get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements
`.prev()` - get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements

This will help you